# Why BFS is used in Edmonds Karp algorithm which make it better with Ford Fulkerson?

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, breadth-first-search

As, when I studied above the Edmonds Karp algorithm, it states that Edmonds Karp uses BFS, so that the complexity doesn't depend on flow value, but I am not able to understand, how BFS helps?

Answer (score 0):

Informally, when E–K pushes flow along a path, each node in the path is further from the source than its predecessor (where distance is defined with respect to the unweighted graph of residual arcs). The key invariant is that no node ever gets closer to the source. As an instantiation of F–F, E–K saturates one of the arcs on the path, whose tail is at some distance d and whose head is at distance d+1. For this arc to become residual again, we have to push flow on the reverse arc, which requires that the tail move to distance d+2. There is an upper bound of |V|−1  on distance, so this cannot happen an arbitrary number of times, as it can with F–F with irrational weights. The subsequent push-relabel algorithms extend this intuition by not recomputing shortest path distances from scratch every time.

(I'm told that CLRS has a formal proof.)